# Why doesn't Java have a file copy?

Tags: java

Why does Java not have a file copy method? This seems like such an obvious thing to have, and it saves people from writing things like [this example](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/CopyFile.shtml).

Comment: It does now, as of Java 7. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Java API is missing more than just file copying. You might be interested in checking out the [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) libraries. For example, the [IO library's](http://commons.apache.org/io/) [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) provides file copying methods.

Comment: Yes, whenever I think to myself "Why is this feature not in Java?", invariably it is implemented by "the commons".

Comment: Which is fair enough - Java is a language, not a library.  It's meant to make things *implementable*, not necessarily implement them in the JDK libraries.

Comment: It's a language and a library (java.util.*).  Why can I write to a file, but not copy one?

Comment: You can write the code to copy a file, if you need to. My guess is that the developers of Java figured it was easy enough to do on your own, so they didn't write a method for it themselves.

Comment: @C. Ross: 'Cause what else are entry level CS classes supposed to use as quiz material?

Comment: @C Ross: Copying a file is a composition of lower level actions, reading, and writing.  Writing to a file however is not a composition of lower level actions.  If you can't write a file in java, you have no way to implement it using other parts of the system.

Answer (score 7):

My guess is because when the File io system was written, they decided they did not want to deal with the cross-platform problems of copying files, and punted - i.e. they said "this is doable by others, and is not that common".

One thing to keep in mind about Java is that it is cross-platform, so some things are more difficult because of that reality.

Comment: "write once, debug everywhere"

Comment: Perhaps, but reading bytes from an input stream and writing them to an output stream is portable everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

`java.io.File` is a relatively simple class introduced in 1.0. JDK 1.0 didn't have much in it - mostly related to support for applets and the javac compiler. I guess there hasn't been a great deal of pressure to expand it - applets and enterprise software are not oriented in that direction.

However, lots has been added to I/O for JDK7. Including [`java.nio.file.Path.copyTo`][1].

[1]: http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#copyTo(java.nio.file.Path, java.nio.file.CopyOption...)

Comment: Just looking through the Java 7 nio.files package, it looks like they added quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

For the same reason Java does not have many other things. which end up being implemented by external libraries.
I am sure you can easily find such a [library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/filecopylibrary/), or you can write a function.